# How to construct <input> in javascript with custom placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Custom placeholders can be constructed along with text areas in Javascript like this:

```
var custom_placeholder = "hello";

html = '<textarea class="form-control">' + custom_placeholder + '</textarea>';
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do this for input tags. Below does not work. The custom placeholder appears outside the input box. So how can this be done?

```
html += '<input type="text"/>' + custom_placeholder;
```

The following syntax is not allowed as well.

```
html += '<input type="text">' + custom_placeholder + '</input>';
```

Comment: use `.attr()` to set placeholder

Comment: @guradio is there no way to do it within the construction of the element?

Comment: somthing like `'<input type="text" "placeholder"="'+custom_placeholder+'">'` just concat it properly

Comment: @KevinB is this really a custom placeholder as you call it? To me "hello" is the innerText of the <textarea> element. A placeholder is an attribute of an html element such as <textarea placeholder="hello">inner text</textarea>

Comment: @KevinB if you use @guradio's suggestion, you should sanitize your custom_placeholder to make sure it doesn't contain, or escapes, any quote characters. Or you could use `.attr('placeholder', ...)` as suggested earlier, which takes care of it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use html input's placeholder attribute to set placeholder text:

```js
let html,customPlaceholder;
html += '<input type="text" placeholder="' + customPlaceholder + '" />'
```

Or, if what you are looking for is actually a preset value (that the user will have to delete to enter their own input), use html's value attribute:

```js
let html,customPlaceholder;
html += '<input type="text" value="' + customPlaceholder + '" />'
```

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: @KevinB this answer is similar to mine, is posted after 7 minutes, doesn't have any explanation and provide wrong Demos. do you really see it as the best anwser? I doubt it.

Comment: @chskd I believe this person was perhaps looking for a preset value instead of a placeholder. But yes, your answer was proper for what they actually asked for. Also, how have I provided wrong demos?

Comment: @chsdk I was looking for preset value, and confused it with placeholder, this was the only answer that talked about both. I will upvote your answer though

Comment: @Slam the snippets don't run (html not defined error), just define html and it's good to go

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to concatenate the `placeholder`attribute within your String, like this:

```
html += '<input type="text" placeholder="' + custom_placeholder + '"/>';
```

**Demo:**

This is a working snippet:

```js
var html = "";
var custom_placeholder = "A Text input";

html += '<input type="text" placeholder="' + custom_placeholder + '"/>';

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

**Note:**

- You better create the elements dynamically and append their
  attributes using JavaScript.
- You don't need `</input>` for inputs in HTML, just add a `/` before closing your input tag.
- Also make sure the `custom_placeholder` variable doesn't contain special characters such as `"` or `'`.

Comment: You might want to mention the need to sanitize the `custom_placeholder` so that it doesn't contain, or escapes, any quote characters, or generally anything else that can't be used directly in HTML. Using JQuery's `.attr()` or the native `.setAttribute()` would already take care of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

### Vanilla JS

```js
var txt = 'Hello',
    input = document.createElement('input');
    
input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
input.setAttribute('placeholder', txt);

document.body.appendChild(input);
```

### jQuery

```js
var txt = 'Hello';

$('body').append('<input type="text">');
$('input').attr('placeholder', txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP wants to set the placeholder during construction of the element. Your solution is applying the attribute from an existing element.

Comment: OK. I modified my answer. The "input" element is now built dynamically. :)